# Testint spark with several parameters and accumulator

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark

I have a unitTest in `SparkStreaming` which has an input parameters.
-DStream[String]

Inside of the code I want to update an `LongAccumulator`. When I execute the test I get an `NullPointerException` because the accumulator doesn't exist. Is there any way to test this?

My accumulator is updated in different methods.

```
class Example(conf: Conf)  {
    var accumulator : LongAccumulator= _

    def start(ssc: StreamingContext, ...) = {
       accumulator = ssc.sc.longAccumulator("Orpahns")
       //I could add accumulator as parameter in execute methods... but runAction doesn't admint two parameters.               
       execute(...)
    }
    def execute(stream: DStream[String]): Unit = {
        stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
          rdd.foreach { r =>
            if (r == "A"){
              acc.add(1)
              sendKafka(...)
            }
        }      
    }
```

It's possible to test this kind of method?

```
runAction[String](input, service.execute)
```

When it try to update the accumulator it doesn't work because it doesn't have inited. I could add a new parameter to the execute method, and it's okay, but `runAction` doesn't admint more parameters either.

Comment: Where is `acc` defined? Please post a MCVE.

Comment: I have edit the question. What does it mean MCVE?

Comment: MCVE is a [mcve].